# jQuery DateTimePicker with dropdows for selecting the time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to have a DateTimePicker which will be able to select the Time using two dropdowns. 
I don't need solutions with slidbars.

Comment: sincerely I don't understand...al this downvotes. While it is trivial to implement a couple of selects for handling the time part...having it together with a calendar to set also the date part on the same DateTime is not completely trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Component you want is here

http://umcdatetimepicker.codeplex.com/

also

http://razum.si/jQuery-calendar/TimeCalendar.html

hope this will help you.